# Generate backtrace and restart

Tags: gdb, backtracking

The way i am starting app and handle it's core dumps is.

Running using `run` and view backtraces using `bt full`.

Can that be done automatically, then restarting the application (and running it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy with a simple gdb script.

Source of multirun.gdb:

```
while 1
  run
  bt
end
```

---

Start gdb as usual, then do "source multirun.gdb". This will keep running your application until it stops, then it will do bt, and restart... You can add "set pagination off" and maybe direct log to some file (see "set logging").